# Как сделать правильное отображение данных при сортировке данных в React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, frontend

Кто может подсказать как правильнее мне применить мою сортировку в React. У меня есть список данных которые я получаю из Firebase это **books1** они изначально отображаются друг за другом в таком формате:

**{"Name": "Javascript", "Author": "Den", "Year": "2015", "raiting": 5, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
{"Name": "Java", "Author": "Den", "Year": "2017", "raiting": 5, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
{"Name": "Linux", "Author": "Den", "Year": "2015", "raiting": 5, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
{"Name": "SQL", "Author": "Den", "Year": "2018", "raiting": 5, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
{"Name": "Python", "Author": "Tom", "Year": "2016", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
{"Name": "Книга для новичков", "Author": "Leo", "Year": "2017", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
...**

Но мне их нужно отсортировать вначале по годам, а потом уже в алфавитном порядке. Что я собственно и сделал, но на чистом JavaScript, но не знаю как это все правильно теперь применить в React.

Вот успешный код логики который я писал на чистом JS для сортировки по годам и в алфавитном порядке книги, и хочу применить в React

```
let list_copy = {
  books_copy:{
    
  }
}
 
let db = [
  {"Name": "Javascript", "Author": "Den", "Year": "2015", "raiting": 5, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Java", "Author": "Den", "Year": "2017", "raiting": 5, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Linux", "Author": "Den", "Year": "2015", "raiting": 5, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "SQL", "Author": "Den", "Year": "2018", "raiting": 5, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Python", "Author": "Tom", "Year": "2016", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Matlab", "Author": "Mark", "Year": "2014", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Pascal", "Author": "Tom", "Year": "2016", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Excel", "Author": "Mark", "Year": "2018", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "C#", "Author": "Leo", "Year": "2017", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Линукс", "Author": "Leo", "Year": "2020", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Виндовс", "Author": "Leo", "Year": "2017", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Книга для новичков", "Author": "Leo", "Year": "2017", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Базовые основы языков", "Author": "David", "Year": "2020", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Грокаем алгоритмы", "Author": "David", "Year": "2015", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Изучаем язык вместе", "Author": "David", "Year": "2020", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
  {"Name": "Jenkins", "Author": "David", "Year": "2018", "raiting": 4, "ISBN": 67556-5656},
 
]
 
let year = [] //массив под  года
 
//сортируем года по возрастанию
function sort(){
      for(let i = 0; i < db.length; i++){
          db[i].Year = Number(db[i].Year)
      }
      db.sort((a, b) => a.Year > b.Year ? 1 : -1);
  }
sort()
 
//заносим уникальные года и сортируем их в порядке на увеличение
function year_array(){
  for(let i = 0; i < db.length; i++){
    year.push(db[i].Year)
  }
  year = year.filter((item, index) => year.indexOf(item) === index) //удаляем дубликаты
}
 
year_array()
 
//добавяем массив с годами
function sort_year(){
  for(let i = 0; i < year.length; i++){
    list_copy.books_copy[year[i]] = [] //создаем пустой массив под каждый год
  }
  //сортируем книги по годам
  for(let i = 0; i < year.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < db.length; j++){
      if(db[j].Year == year[i]){
        list_copy.books_copy[year[i]].push(db[j])
      }
    }
  }
}
 
sort_year()
 
//сортировка по имени
 
function sort_name(){
  for(let j = 0; j < Object.keys(list_copy.books_copy).length; j++){
    list_copy.books_copy[year[j]].sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name));
  }
}
sort_name()
  console.log(list_copy.books_copy)
```

Вот такой формат я получаю на выходе как и положено

```
"books_copy":{
"2014":[
{
"Name":"Matlab",
"Author":"Mark",
"Year":2014,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
}
],
"2015":[
{
"Name":"Грокаем алгоритмы",
"Author":"David",
"Year":2015,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
},
{
"Name":"Javascript",
"Author":"Den",
"Year":2015,
"raiting":5,
"ISBN":61900
},
{
"Name":"Linux",
"Author":"Den",
"Year":2015,
"raiting":5,
"ISBN":61900
}
],
"2016":[
{
"Name":"Pascal",
"Author":"Tom",
"Year":2016,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
},
{
"Name":"Python",
"Author":"Tom",
"Year":2016,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
}
],
"2017":[
{
"Name":"Виндовс",
"Author":"Leo",
"Year":2017,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
},
{
"Name":"Книга для новичков",
"Author":"Leo",
"Year":2017,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
},
{
"Name":"C#",
"Author":"Leo",
"Year":2017,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
},
{
"Name":"Java",
"Author":"Den",
"Year":2017,
"raiting":5,
"ISBN":61900
}
],
"2018":[
{
"Name":"Excel",
"Author":"Mark",
"Year":2018,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
},
{
"Name":"Jenkins",
"Author":"David",
"Year":2018,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
},
{
"Name":"SQL",
"Author":"Den",
"Year":2018,
"raiting":5,
"ISBN":61900
}
],
"2020":[
{
"Name":"Базовые основы языков",
"Author":"David",
"Year":2020,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
},
{
"Name":"Изучаем язык вместе",
"Author":"David",
"Year":2020,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
},
{
"Name":"Линукс",
"Author":"Leo",
"Year":2020,
"raiting":4,
"ISBN":61900
}
]
}
```

А вот как у меня выглядит компонент на React, где тупо решил вставить функции с логикой из чистого JS сортировки и в дальнейшем поменять **books1** на мой отсортированный **list_copy** при рендеринге, но тут так как-то делать нельзя и нужно что-то предпринимать другое но не знаю как, возможно нужно создавать какой-то еще один стейт и что-то добавлять туда...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import firebase from '../../firebase';
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
const MainPage = () => {
 
    const [books1, setBooks] = useState([])
    let history = useHistory();
 
    const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('books1');
 
    const getBooksList = () => {
        ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot)=> {
            const list = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
                list.push(doc.data());
            });
            setBooks(list)
        })
    };
 
    const deleteBook = (id) => {
        ref
            .doc(id)
            .delete()
            .catch((err) =>{
                console.error(err);
            })
    }
 
    const editBook = (id) => {
        history.push('/editbook/' + id)
    }
 
 
 
    useEffect(() => {
        getBooksList();
    }, [])
 
    let list_copy = {
        books_copy:{
    
        }
    }
 
    let year = []
 
    //сортируем года по возрастанию
function sort(){
      for(let i = 0; i < books1.length; i++){
          books1[i].Year = Number(books1[i].Year)
      }
      books1.sort((a, b) => a.Year > b.Year ? 1 : -1);
  }
sort()
 
//создаем отдельный массив под года
function year_array(){
  for(let i = 0; i < books1.length; i++){
    year.push(books1[i].Year)
  }
  year = year.filter((item, index) => year.indexOf(item) === index) //удаляем дубликаты
}
 
year_array()
 
 
function sort_year(){
  for(let i = 0; i < year.length; i++){
    list_copy.books_copy[year[i]] = []
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < year.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < books1.length; j++){
      if(books1[j].Year == year[i]){
        list_copy.books_copy[year[i]].push(books1[j])
      }
    }
  }
}
 
sort_year()
 
//сортировка по имени
 
function sort_name(){
  for(let j = 0; j < Object.keys(list_copy.books_copy).length; j++){
    list_copy.books_copy[year[j]].sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name));
  }
}
sort_name()
 
 
 
    return(
        <>
        <div>
            <p>Test </p>
            {list_copy.books_copy.map((c) =>(
                <div key={c.id}>
                    <p>Год: </p>
                    <div>
                        <h5>{c.Name}</h5>
                        <p>Автор: {c.Author}</p>
                        <p>Год публикации: {c.Year}</p>
                        <p>Рейтинг: {c.Raiting}</p>
                        <p>ISBN: {c.ISBN}</p>
                        <button onClick={() => deleteBook(c.id)}>Удалить</button>
                        <button onClick={() => editBook(c.id)}>Изменить</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
 
export default MainPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // выводим эту функцию в отдельный файл.
    export const getSortedItems = (array) => {
      // что-бы не мутировать входной массив 
      let books1 = [...array];
      let list_copy = {
        books_copy: {},
      };
      let year = [];
      // сортируем года по возрастанию
      function sort() {
        for (let i = 0; i < books1.length; i++) {
          books1[i].Year = Number(books1[i].Year);
        }
        books1.sort((a, b) => (a.Year > b.Year ? 1 : -1));
      }
      sort();
      // создаем отдельный массив под года
      function year_array() {
        for (let i = 0; i < books1.length; i++) {
          year.push(books1[i].Year);
        }
        year = year.filter((item, index) => year.indexOf(item) === index); //удаляем дубликаты
      }
      year_array();
    
      function sort_year() {
        for (let i = 0; i < year.length; i++) {
          list_copy.books_copy[year[i]] = [];
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < year.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < books1.length; j++) {
            if (books1[j].Year === year[i]) {
              list_copy.books_copy[year[i]].push(books1[j]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      sort_year();
      // сортировка по имени
      function sort_name() {
        for (let j = 0; j < Object.keys(list_copy.books_copy).length; j++) {
          list_copy.books_copy[year[j]].sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name));
        }
      }
      sort_name();
    
      return list_copy;
    };

import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getSortedItems } from '../utils/getSortedItems';
import firebase from '../../firebase';
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

const MainPage = () => {
  const [books1, setBooks] = useState([]);
  let history = useHistory();

  const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('books1');

  const getBooksList = () => {
    ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot)=> {
        const list = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
            list.push(doc.data());
        });
        setBooks(list)
    })
  };

  const deleteBook = (id) => {
      ref
          .doc(id)
          .delete()
          .catch((err) =>{
              console.error(err);
          })
  }

  const editBook = (id) => {
      history.push('/editbook/' + id)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getBooksList();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p>Test </p>
        {Object.entries(getSortedItems(books1).books_copy).map(([key, values], index) => (
          <Fragment key={index}>
            <p>Год: {key}</p>
            {values.map((value) => (
              <div key={value.id}>
                <div>
                  <h5>{value.Name}</h5>
                  <p>Автор: {value.Author}</p>
                  <p>Год публикации: {value.Year}</p>
                  <p>Рейтинг: {value.Raiting}</p>
                  <p>ISBN: {value.ISBN}</p>
                  <button onClick={() => deleteBook(values.id)}>Удалить</button>
                  <button onClick={() => editBook(values.id)}>Изменить</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </А>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MainPage;
```